# Can I use variables to change the display name of a button?

Tags: html, variables, button, video

I have this button:

```
<button onclick="goHD()">HD</button>
```

That changes the video size to HD and back to SD (not the file, it changes the size of the video window from 360p to 720p and the other way around, the video is 1280x720):

```
function goHD() {
if (myVideo.width != 1280)
    myVideo.width = 1280
else
    myVideo.width = 720;
}
```

But I want to change the name of the button from HD (when the video is in SD, so that the user can select to view it in HD) to SD (so that the user can change to view the video in SD).

Is there a way to create a variable that can do something like this?

```
"if video size = 720p
change var = SD

if video size = 360p
change var = HD"
```

OR

```
function goHD() {
if (myVideo.width != 1280)
    myVideo.width = 1280
    "change var = SD"
else
    myVideo.width = 720
    "change var = HD";
}
```

NOTE: I am new at coding and I am trying to keep this simple and not involve jquery right now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass `this` object to `goHD()` and then

JS

```
function goHD(el) {
    if (myVideo.width != 1280){
        myVideo.width = 1280
        el.innerHTML="SD"
    }
    else{
        myVideo.width = 720
        el.innerHTML = "HD";
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<button onclick="goHD(this)">HD</button>
```

Comment: Hmm... I don't think I understand what you mean by "pass this object to goHD()" but it worked in my code :D

Comment: @AndréSá by passing `this` you pass a reference to your button Element which can be manipulated inside your function

Comment: Oh, Thank you! :D If I were to use an image (to do that onclick action), lets say HD_icon.png and SD_icon.png, would it be the same procedure? If so, what would I have to use instead of the button?

Comment: then you have to change the `src` instead of `innerHTML`. and you have to use `img` element to display images

Comment: What if I wish to create a new button that instead of altering the size of the video window, it pauses the video and changes it's name from pause to play?

Comment: @AndréSá then call the function to `play/pause` accordingly and change the property that is responsible for `name` please try to understand the concept behind the code as then you don't have to ask for every change you made